# Sub-module not found after changing parameter through chparam in a foreach loop

Tags: yosys

I am trying to synthesize a module for different values of a parameter. I am changing the parameter with a `foreach` loop in tcl and passing the updated parameter to the top module using `-chparam` tag in the `hierarchy` command. It works for the first iteration of the loop. However, in the second iteration, it shows the error that one of the sub-modules is not found.

I have written a simple module (written in `test.sv`) to demonstrate the problem.

```
module top #(parameter N = 8)(
    input [N-1:0] x,
    output y
);

    isZero #(.N(N)) isZero_inst(
        .x(x),
        .y(y)
    );

endmodule


module isZero #(parameter N = 8)(
    input [N-1:0] x,
    output y
);

    assign y = |x;

endmodule
```

I am using the following tcl command  (written in `test.tcl`):

```
yosys -import

read_verilog -defer -sv  test.sv 

foreach N [list 4 8] {
    hierarchy -check -top top -chparam N $N 
    procs; opt; 
    flatten; opt; 
    techmap; opt;
    abc; opt; 
    clean; opt;
    opt_clean -purge
    write_verilog -noattr -noexpr test_${N}_syn.v
}
```

It generates the first file: `test_4_syn.v`. However, in the second iteration, it shows the error:

```
Module `\isZero' referenced in module `\top' in cell `\isZero_inst' is not part of the design.
```

For completeness: I am using the following command to run the tcl file:

```
yosys -c test.tcl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hierarchy` is the main part of elaboration, and IIRC will purge non-parameterised versions of parameterised modules.

The `design` command is a good way of dealing with this without re-running `read_verilog`. e.g.:

```
yosys -import

read_verilog -defer -sv  test.sv 
design -stash test

foreach N [list 4 8] {
    design -load test
    hierarchy -check -top top -chparam N $N 
    procs; opt; 
    flatten; opt; 
    techmap; opt;
    abc; opt; 
    clean; opt;
    opt_clean -purge
    write_verilog -noattr -noexpr test_${N}_syn.v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the `read_verilog` inside the `foreach` loop with `-overwrite` tag (without `-overwrite` Yosys would generate redefinition of module error). This is how the tcl file looks now:

```
foreach N [list 4 8] {
    read_verilog -overwrite -defer -sv  test.sv
    hierarchy -check -top top -chparam N $N 
    procs; opt; 
    flatten; opt; 
    techmap; opt;
    abc; opt; 
    clean; opt;
    opt_clean -purge
    write_verilog -noattr -noexpr test_${N}_syn.v
}
```

I am not sure if this is the proper approach, but it works. I know that in Synopsys Design Compiler the files are read only once.